# How to proprely modify a 2d array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

HI I'm getting a segfault with this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main()
{
    char **array;
    int i = 0;

    array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 20);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 20);
        array[i] = "____________________";
    }
    array[0][0] = '2';
    return(0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
I'm very confused when I need to modify 2d arrays, what are my best options here  ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You get a segfault because with `array[i] = "____________________";` you let point each `array[i]` to a string literal. Note that you do not copy the contents of the literal but let `array[i]` directly point to it. Consequently, with `array[0][0] = '2'` you are altering a string literal then, which is undefined behaviour (very likely to become apparent as a segfault in this case).

Use `strcpy(array[i],"____________________);` instead.

BTW: write `array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (20+1));` (note the `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char*)` here and the `+1` for the string termination character).

Comment: oh ok I see but isn't strdup better in this case ? and im mallocating 20 string so why the type shouldn't be (char *) ?

Comment: you can use `strdup` as well, though it is not standard.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is *defined* to be 1.